# How to install Java 8 or higher on Debian 8 given the jessie-backports are no more valid?

Tags: java-8, installation, package, debian-jessie

I had tried the following two ways but no luck

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list

echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list

apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update && apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y
```

I get error saying

```
Unable to find the oracle8-java-installer package
```

---

I tried openjdk-8-jdk too but no luck

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN echo deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra_debian.list  >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra_debian.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

```
Step 9/9 : RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
 ---> Running in eaf2278dd79f
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package openjdk-8-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Comment: Any specific use case to choose oracle java 8? You can try openjdk. install it using command `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` if not already.

Comment: @AsSiDe I tried that too. Please see my updated question